# Plugin to achieve drag and drop effect of blocks using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, react, drag-drop

Whats a good plugin to achieve drag and drop effect similar to Trello card movement?   Preferably based off material design.  Im using React.js.

Comment: I use the js library sortable https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable

Comment: OP, are you still interested in this question? Did you already find an answer? If so, can you share it with us?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend LMDD drag and drop script.
Demo page here:
https://supraniti.github.io/Lean-Mean-Drag-and-Drop/